# The function output result from the while loop is giving the wrong value

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to read a file. After collection the data, one line at a time, I would like to have a display of results before further manipulations. The function I use is below:

```
def reading(repository):
file = open("pmacollection.txt", 'r')
while (True):
    line = file.readline()
    if (len(line) == 0):
        break
   # print(line, end = "")
    elif (line.isdigit()):
        print("Line '" + line + "' is a number")
    elif (line == line[::-1]):
        print("Line '" + line + "' is a palindrome.")
    elif (line != line[::-1]):
        print("Line '" + line + "' is not")
file.close()
return None
```

I tried a variety of things, but I can not figure it out, why I always get "not a palindrome", no matter what I input. I tested the if-elif-else construction, and for some reason it wont work, which it should. Am I missing something? Also, the part after the +line+ is printed on the next line, I thought that placing the end="" would fix it, but it did not. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Edit: As many suggested, I used split to remove the \n generated by readfile(). As virxen, Matiiss and Johnny Mopp suggested. It also solved the main problem. I did not realise they were even connected, but apparently the programme was reading the same line over and over (line != line[::-1]), exactly because of the space from readfile().

Comment: `readline()` includes the newline.

Comment: use `.strip()`: `line = file.readline().strip()` or `line = line.strip()` after the current `line = file.readline()`. This is to remove the `\n` @JohnnyMopp mentioned (and other stuff too but in this case it will probably be just the `\n`)

Comment: I see. Would stripping remove just the white space at the end? I am reading the documentation, it seem it not just the \n removal. I am not sure it is a problem even. I will give it a go. Thank you both.

Comment: you can use rstrip to remove only from the end of string and with parameter \n to remove only \n    ---------------->line = file.readline().rstrip("\n")

Comment: `readline()` isn't *generating* the newline at the end of the line: it is *reporting* what is in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and use `.readlines()` which returns a list of all lines. Also, it uses a `"\n"` to state that a new line started from there. So, you just need to strip it using `.strip("\n")`

z.txt

```
999888999
122342342
97823
9009
10233201
```

More pythonic way is using `with` statement.

```
with open("z.txt","r") as f:
    f1=f.readlines()
    for line in f1:
        if line.strip("\n")[::-1]==line.strip("\n"):
            print(line.strip("\n")," is a palindrome.")
        else:
            print(line.strip("\n")," is not a palindrome.")
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be somewhere between the array indexing or a break missing. If you always get the same result, it most likely points to an invalid array indexer, or simply the array index (line number) isn't changing.

Not very familiar with python, but from a C++ point of view, it does look like you're code is always reading the same line.